# How to set the default WIFI network in mac?

Tags: macos, wifi, default, wifimanager, ssid

My Mac is getting connected to a default network always. I want to change the default wifi network. How can i do that?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: but still helpful for programmers

Answer (score 16):

Go to your Network Preferences ==> Advanced
In this menu, you'll see all your networks that are known.
The order of the list, determines the order to connect to.